# Show that the sequence $(a_n)$ divergent by using the formal definition of convergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = 2(-1)^n-2$ for all positive integer $n$.
Show that the sequence $(a_n)$ divergent by using the formal definition of convergence of a sequence.

**Attempt:**
For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $(a_n)$ convergent to some real number $L$. Then, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for any positive integer $n$ for which $n \ge N$, we have
$$|a_n - L|<1.$$
Now, consider two cases of the parity of $n$.

- If $n$ is odd, then
  $$|a_n-L|<1 \implies |-4-L|=|L+4|<1 \implies -5<L<-3.$$
- If $n$ is even, then
  $$|a_n-L|<1 \implies |0-L|=|L|<1 \implies -1<L<1.$$

Therefore, $L \in (-5,-3) \cap (-1,1) = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction. Hence, the sequence $(a_n)$ is divergent.

Is it true?

Comment: This indeed works.